# Ant on vertex of pyramid expected number of seconds to return to original vertex

Tags: probability, expected-value

> An ant is walking on a square pyramid. It starts at a random vertex, and from there, it can only go to an adjacent vertex. It takes the ant one second to go to an adjacent vertex. What is the expected number of seconds the ant takes to return to its original vertex.

I only know how to do this for if the ant is on the apex, and I'm not sure how to proceed if it was an arbitrary vertex.

If it was the apex, the ant must take $1$ second to one of the other four adjacent vertices. From the new vertex it is on, it can go to any of the three other adjacent vertices, and it has a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of going back to the original vertex. However, if it doesn't go to the original vertex, the new vertex it is on still has a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of going back to the original vertex. We could treat this as a "three sided die" with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ of getting a desired result. With states, we can find that the expected number of seconds to get a desired result will be $3.$ Adding this to the first second the ant moved to another adjacent vertex, we get an answer of $4$ seconds if it was the apex.

However, I have to consider what happens if it was the other vertices? May I have some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your work seems to assume the pyramid is a square pyramid. Are you sure this is what the problem implies? If it were a triangular pyramid for instance, then all vertices are symmetric so you don't need to have two cases.

Comment: @angryavian Oh, sorry. My bad. I meant that it was a square pyramid

Comment: If it is a square pyramid, may I have a hint on how to proceed to work this out? :)

Comment: Also, even if I get the expected number of seconds for the other cases, how will I find the total expected number of seconds?

Comment: For a random walk (with fixed starting point) on a connected finite graph, the expected time to return to the starting point is $2e/d$ where $e$ is the number of edges and $d$ is the degree of the starting point. For your square pyramid it's $16/4$ if you start at the apex, $16/3$ if you start at a base vertex. With a random starting point then it's $(1/5)(16/4)+(4/5)(16/3)=76/15$.

Comment: @bof wow that's a cool formula! Is there any way to derive it? Also, is there a name for it?

Comment: So I've done something similar to @Kolmogorov's answer. https://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/erdos.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I had misread the question, so I am giving a revised answer.

As you have already found out, if you start from the apex, the expected time to return is $4s$

Let us call the apex a, and the $4$ base vertices as *b,c,d,e* (clockwise,say)

To find the expected time to start from and return from any base vertex, say *b*, we apply first step analysis

One step from *b*, eg will land us at *a,c,e* with $Pr = \frac13$ each

Similarly, one step from *a* will land us at *c,d,e* with $Pr = \frac14$ each, **or we are back home** at *b* Framing equations in this manner, we get

$\displaylines{b = 1+ (a+c+e)/3 \\a = 1+ (c+d+e)/4 \\c = 1+(a+d)/3\\d=1+(a+c+e)/3\\e=1+(a+d)/3}$

Solving this gives the answer $b = \frac{16}3$

and the expected time from a random vertex $= \frac{4(1+16/3)}{5} =  \frac{76}{15}s $

This tallies with the results of @bof, who has used graph theory

Comment: did you mean to let $b$ be any of the base vertices? Also here, what is Pr

Comment: Oh wait , pr is an abbreviation for probability.

Comment: Yes, base vertices, since the ant only travels to the vertices. *Pr* is the probability  at a given time for the ant to be at the apex or the base vertices.

Comment: Btw, the formulation I have given would be useful if you were asked the probability of the ant being at the apex after, say, $10s$

Comment: I don't understand. The problem says the ant starts at a random vertex, and has to return to its original vertex. But you seem to be assuming it starts at the apex. I get an expected return time of $\frac{16}3$ if the ant starts at a base vertex, and $\frac{76}{15}$ starting at a random vertex.

Comment: @bof: Sorry, I missed the "random vertex" part. Since I haven't read graph theory, I'm deleting my answer. But I'd like to know if there are other methods to tackle such problems.

Comment: The idea as I recall is to express the return time as the sum of $16$ (twice the number of edges) random variables, each of which counts the number of times a particular edge is traversed in a particular direction. And somehow reason cleverly that their expectations are all equal. And finally consider the $d$ edges leaving the starting vertex, which must each have expectation $1/d$.

Comment: @bof: Thanks a lot. I have revised my answer using a different approach.

Comment: @trueblueanil I'm a bit confused on why we cannot have the equations $b=1+(a+c+e)/3, a=1+(b+c+d+e)/4, c=1+(b+a+d)/3, d=(e+a+c)/3, e=(b+a+d)/3,$ since isn't $b$ also having a $1/3$ chance when starting at node $E$ or $C$ and has a $1/4$ chance to go to when we start on node $A?$

Comment: sorry, the formatting was a little off. i meant for the last equation to be $e=(b+a+d)/3,$ and the "since" to be after that

Comment: This i s the simplest way to *write* the equations. $1s$ has elapsed, and if the ant has *not* moved to *a* or *d*, it must have returned to *b*. Some people would write the equation as $e = \frac13(a+1) +\frac13(d+1) +\frac13$, the last part showing return to *b*, but you can see that it means the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this problem in a quite straight forward manner using **Markov Chains**. Observe that the vertices and the edges of a square pyramid can be thought of as a graph with $5$ vertices which looks like the following :
[image]

In the above diagram, $H$ denotes the Apex, and the $\square ABCD$ is the base of the pyramid. Suppose, we are starting from any arbitrary vertex. Now, we are performing a random walk on the vertices of this graph. Let us denote the vertices on the base by $v_1 , v_2 , v_3 , v_4$ and the apex by $v_5$. Let us denote their degrees by $D=\{d_1 , d_2 , d_3 , d_4 , d_5\}$.

Consider a Markov Chain $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ on the state space $V = \{v_1 , v_2 , v_3 , v_4 , v_5\}$ with transition matrix $\mathcal{P} = ((p_{i,j}))_{i,j \in V}$ where $p_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = j | X_0 = i)$.

Firstly, the chain is finite. Secondly, observe that even if we start from any vertex, it is possible to reach any other vertex in the graph, since the graph is connected. Thus, the chain is irreducible. So, the chain, being finite and irreducible, has a unique stationary distribution, say $\pi$.

Now, let us state and prove the following well-known result :

> **Result :** For a simple random walk on a finite graph, $\pi_k = \frac{d_k}{\sum d_i}$ , where $\pi_k$ is the $k$-th member of $\pi$, the unique stationary distribution of the chain.
>
> **Proof :** Let $I$ be the indicator fuction on $V$ such that $I(k)=1$ if and only if $k$ is a neighbor of $j$, and $I(k)=0$ otherwise. Then
> $$d_j=\sum_k I(k)=\sum_k d_k \cdot \frac{I(k)}{d_k} = \sum_k d_k p_{kj}\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad D\mathcal{P} = \mathcal{P}$$
> As $\pi$ is the unique stationary distribution, so the result follows.

Again, we know that $m_j = \mathbb{E}\big[\text{Time to return to } j ~|~ X_0 = j\big] = \dfrac{1}{\pi_j}$.

Now, $d_5 = \deg(v_5) = 4$ and for any $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, we have $d_k = \deg(v_k) = 3$. Also, $\sum_k d_k = 3+3+3+3+4 = 16$.

Therefore,

- If we start from the **apex**, expected time to return is $\left(\dfrac{4}{16}\right)^{-1} = ~\boxed{4 ~\text{seconds}}$
- If we start from **any base vertex**, expected time to return is $\left(\dfrac{3}{16}\right)^{-1} = ~\boxed{5\frac{1}{3} ~\text{seconds}}$
- If we start from **any random vertex**, expected time to return is $$4 \times \frac{1}{4+1} + \frac{16}{3} \times \frac{4}{4+1} = \frac{4}{5} + \frac{64}{15} = \frac{76}{15} = ~\boxed{5\frac{1}{15} ~\text{seconds}}$$

---

Please let me know if this is understandable to you or not.

Comment: Oh wait, the formula that bof used is essentially what you derived. Sorry for my slow understanding of your solutions, I'm not very used to markov chains, matrices, and things like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what with transition matrix $P=((pi,j))i,j\in V$ where $p_{ij}=P(X_1=j|X_0=i)$ means. I'm not very familiar with this type of notation so could I have a further explanation of this part?

Comment: Transition matrix is one of the most basic things which you need to know while studying the theory of Markov chains. Since you do not have clear idea about a transition matrix, I believe it'll be better if you study these things a little bit, and have a look at my answer once again. I'm pretty sure you'll understand. :)